# Cambiar valor 0 a 1 en sql mediante checkbox en php

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

Tengo un formulario con un checkbox y campos de una consulta sql de esta manera:

checkbox - datos del registro

El checkbox tiene que estar marcado o no dependiendo del valor que tiene en la base de datos. Es un campo tinyint que le he puesto un condicional al cargar la página que si es 1, lo marque, y si es cero, no lo haga.

El usuario marcará los checkbox que crea oportuno y al enviar el formulario, me genera un query que actualiza la tabla y todos los registros de la tabla en el campo relacionado al checkbox.

Este es el código del form:

```
$inscritos[]=$columna['ArLicencia'];
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$inscritos[$i]."\" value=\"0\">"; // incluido para evitar valores null
            echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"".$inscritos[$i]."\" value =".$columna['ArAsiste'];


            if ($columna['ArAsiste'] == 1){
                echo " checked";
            }
```

Al enviar el formulario, en la página de la acción, me extrae un string con las licencias (ArLicencia) y lo separa.

Por otro lado, me extrae un string con los valores de los checkbox de este tipo:

Como nombre, la licencia y como valor, el valor que está marcado. En teoría debería ser 0 para no marcado, y 1 para marcado.

```
$inscritos = $_POST['listado'];

$arrayinscritos = explode(",",$inscritos);

foreach ($arrayinscritos as &$valor){

$valor2 = $_POST[$valor];
if ($valor2 == 1){

    $licenciasinscritas[]=$valor;

}
if ($valor2 == 0){

    $licenciasquenovan[]=$valor;


}
}
```

Con esto lo que hago es crear dos string, uno con las licencias marcadas y otras con las no marcadas. Después, creo la consulta a ejecutar para actualizar el campo ArAsiste como 1 o como 0.

El problema es que cuando marco la casilla, no me devuelve un 1.

Por ejemplo, tengo dos licencias, las marco, y al imprimir lo que me devuelve, es esto:

(83209 - 0)(92742 - 0)

Y si no las chequeo, me devuelve lo mismo.

¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Cual es el post listado? porque tu variable en el foreach tiene un amperson(&), se supon que si un checkbox no está marcado no manda el valor, en vez de poner un mae a cada checkbox, pon un name generico, por ejemplo marcados[] y el valor el $inscritos[$i] y al hacer un $_POST[$marcados] te traerá un arreglo con todos los nombres marcados.

Tu pregunta es clara, pero los procesos que haces a mi parecer no, trata de ser un poco más detallado en eso.

Comment: El post listado extrae todas las licencias, con lo que envía un string con todas ellas mediante POST. Le hago un implode con una coma antes de enviarlo, luego, lo recupero en la página de acción y le hago un explode para separarlos.

Le asigno como nombre, el nombre de la licencia. Si le pongo como valor, la licencia, no me devolverá un 1.

Ahora mismo estoy en el punto que los checkbox marcados me mandan un 0, no un 1.

Comment: Si cambio el tipo checkbox por tipo "text" e introduzco manualmente 1 o 0, funciona perfecto.